Formula in "Le calcul des résidus et ses applications à la théorie des fonctions" by Ernst Lindelöf,
I'm studying the text, "Le calcul des résidus et ses
applications à la théorie des fonctions" by Ernst Lindelöf, at page 77 he starts the proof of formula X, the passage that I find unclear is when he claims that:
$$-\int^{\alpha+i\infty}_{\alpha-i\infty}\frac{f(z)}{e^{\pi i z}-e^{-\pi i z}}dz=-2\int^{\infty}_{0}Q_1(\alpha,t)dt$$
where the function $Q_1(\tau,t)$
is defined as $$Q_1(\tau,t):=p(\tau,t)X_1(\tau,t)+q(\tau,t)\Psi_1(\tau,t)$$
where $p(\tau,t)$ is the real part of the function $f(\tau+it)$ i.e.
$p(\tau,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[f(\tau+it)+f(\tau-it)\right]$.
$q(\tau,t)$ is the imaginary part of the function $f(\tau+it)$ i.e. $q(\tau,t)=\frac{1}{2i}\left[f(\tau+it)-f(\tau-it)\right]$.
and we define $X_1$ and $\Psi_1$ as:
$$\left \{ \begin{array}{rl}
 \Psi_1(\tau,t):=\frac{\cos(\pi \tau)(e^{\pi t}-e^{-\pi t})}{e^{2\pi t}+e^{-2\pi t}-2\cos(2\pi \tau)}\\
 X_1(\tau,t):=\frac{\sin(\pi\tau)(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})}{e^{2\pi t}+e^{-2\pi t}-2\cos(2\pi \tau)}
\end{array}
\right.$$
notice that we have:
$$\frac{1}{e^{\pi i z}-e^{-\pi i z}}=-\left[\Psi_1(\tau,t)+iX_1(\tau,t)\right]$$.
I have clearly understood that $\frac{1}{e^{\pi i z}-e^{-\pi i z}}=-\left[\Psi_1(\tau,t)+iX_1(\tau,t)\right]$, it also makes sense to break both functions in real and imaginary part, at this point I would think that:
$$-\int^{\alpha+i\infty}_{\alpha-i\infty}\frac{f(z)}{e^{\pi i z}-e^{-\pi i z}}dz=-\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{f(\alpha+it)}{e^{\pi i (\alpha+it)}-e^{-\pi i (\alpha+it)}}dt \\
=-\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}[p(\alpha,t)+iq(\alpha,t)][-(\Psi_1(\alpha,t)+iX_1(\alpha,t))]dt
$$
but I don't see how to arrive at $-2\int^{\infty}_{0}Q_1(\alpha,t)dt$.
Can someone help me out?

You've done the hard part, what you want to do at this step is to look at the evenness/oddness of the involved functions in regards to $t$.
$\Psi_1$ is odd, $X_1$ is even, $p$ is even and $q$ is odd wrt $t$. This tells you which term of the final integrand is even and which is odd (noting that you forgot a $+$ to have $p + iq$), and integrating an odd term over $\mathbb{R}$ gives $0$, so that only the even terms contribute to the integral, at twice the value they have on the half-line.
There is also another mistake: the change of variable $z = \alpha + it$ implies that $\mathrm{d}z = i\mathrm{dt}$ and not just $\mathrm{dt}$, so that you get the correct prefactor $-1$ at the end.

Thank you, I see what you are saying, proceeding like you suggested I find that the only terms remaining are the even ones (so exactly the ones defining $Q_1$ and the integral is equal to twice the integral on the half-line;
The problem now is that, computing
$$-\int^{+\infty}{-\infty}[p(\alpha,t)+iq(\alpha,t)][-(\Psi_1(\alpha,t)+iX_1(\alpha,t))]dt$$ I find a factor $i$ in front of the terms, so I don't obtain $-2\int^{\infty}{0} Q_1(\alpha,t) dt$ but $2i\int^{\infty}_{0} Q_1(\alpha,t) dt$

@Zackury Thanks for noticing this issue, I edited my answer in consequence.

Thank you, It works perfectly now
